# Iphone advice for plan involving only texting and calling

Tags: iphone

I want to get an iphone for my daughter but I dont want her on internet all the time, what can I do so that she only has texting and calling?

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in restrictions on the iPhone and disallow to Installing apps as well as Safari. (see this [document from Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201304).

If you wait for iOS 10 which is due this fall you'll then be able to actually [remove most apps](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204221) which might help out even more.